# Yo generator for meanjs 0.5.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, meanjs, yo

I can see below for Yo Generator in meanjs documentation:

`The Yeoman Generator is currently not maintained. It is based on an older version of MEAN.JS (0.4.2). This content is retained here for historical purposes and for anyone still using the generator on their projects.`

So does `The Yeoman Generator is currently not maintained.` means that yo generator may not get updated for meanjs ^0.4.2?

Is there any other generator which can be used to generate new modules for meanjs ^0.4.2?

I didn't find any documentation related to manual creation of mean module? Any link would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I am using the stable version 0.4.2 and it seems ok for me. If you want to do the manual creation of a module, then follow the instructions of the books in the **Resources** tab at the end of the meanjs' [document link](http://example.com) . **Amos Q. Haviv 's MEAN_Web_Development** may give you some help.